# How to display NFTs of Torus wallet?

Tags: reactjs, nft, ethers.js

I've successfully integrated the Torus wallet and now I am trying to display the NFTs that a person has in the wallet. I am doing it successfully with MetaMask but I am having troubles making it work with Torus. I am guessing I have a problem with the provider? I get the following errors on the browser:

```
index.ts:225 Uncaught (in promise) Error: unsupported provider (argument="provider", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.5.2)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:225)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:237)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.ts:241)
    at new Web3Provider (web3-provider.ts:156)
    at loadNFTs (UsersNFTs.js:112)
```

and

```
VM9765:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at <anonymous>:2:315627
    at <anonymous>:2:324225
    at <anonymous>:2:324229
    at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (index.js:1)
```

And this is my code:

*** UsersNFTs.js ***

```
  let [torusSdkInstance,setTorusSdkInstance] = useState()

  // Import dynamically torus wallet object
  useEffect(()=>{
    const initialize = async () => {
      const torus = (await import("@toruslabs/torus-embed")).default;
      setTorusSdkInstance(new torus({}));
    }
    initialize();
  }, [])

const providerOptions = {
    "custom-Torus": { //Torus wallet
      display: {
        logo: 'https://miime.io/images/wallet-login-torus-logo.png',
        name: "Torus",
        description: "Connect to Torus Wallet"
      },
      package: torusSdkInstance,
      options: {
        // apiKey: "EXAMPLE_PROVIDER_API_KEY"
      },
      connector: async (_, options) => {
        await torusSdkInstance.init({
          enableLogging: false,
        });
        await torusSdkInstance.login();
        const web3 = new Web3(torusSdkInstance.provider);
        return web3;
      }
    }
  }


const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
      network: "mainnet",
      cacheProvider: true,
      providerOptions
    });

    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer)
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)
    const data = await marketContract.fetchMyNFTs()
```

*** fetchMyNFTs function in the smart contract ***

```
  function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint itemCount = 0;
    uint currentIndex = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
        itemCount += 1;
      }
    }

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
        uint currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
        MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
        items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
        currentIndex += 1;
      }
    }
   
    return items;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to display the minted NFTs (not the purchased ones) of a wallet, so I want to share my solution!

I have a fetchNFTs function in my smart contract that gets the tokens made available in the market place but not sold yet (address(0)):

```
function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
uint itemCount = _itemIds.current();
uint unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
uint currentIndex = 0;

MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
  if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(0)) {
    uint currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
    MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
    items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
    currentIndex += 1;
  }
}

return items;
}
```

And in the frontend after I call this function, I just had to map through the items and select the ones which the seller address equals the address of the connected wallet, so I get the NFTs that the address has minted but not sold yet.